# What is the easiest way to provide additional installable component for my Android app?

Tags: android

I have an additional component that I can not distribute inside my app. The component is a third-party viewer for a proprietary format, and it is not distributed through Android Market.

So, when a user clicks on a file of that type, I'd like to provide a way to install that third-party viewer with the least effort. By install I mean - download APK, install it and launch through an Intent.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I would think you would need to ask that question of whoever wrote the component. If you are not allowed to distribute it in your app, you probably do not have the rights to distribute it at all. That means whoever wrote it needs to distribute it, and then it will be up to them to tell you how to arrange to get it to end users.

Comment: I have made an agreement with author of that component that I can direct user to install & launch it, so it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host the APK file on a Web server configured for the proper MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`), or Amazon S3 or another service already so configured. Do an `ACTION_VIEW` on the URL. That should let the user install the APK, after validating the security settings and all that jazz.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to make the user change the setting to be able to use software that does not originate from the Android Market?

Comment: @Jean Hominal: Yes, and this technique will not work for AT&T phones, since they do not allow it. However, the OP indicated that the Android Market is not a solution, and so there are no other options that are even partially automated.